# Commutation of Series and Integrals

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis

Since I started to study analysis I have a question, that is not clear for me yet.

If I have the following situation:
$$
 \int_\Omega \left[ \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x) \right] dx <\infty,
$$
where $\Omega$ is a domain of integration and the series converges and define an integrable function. **Question:** Under what conditions we have the following equality

$$ 
\int_\Omega \left[ \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x) \right] dx= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_\Omega f_n(x) dx?
$$

Comment: Are you familiar with any of the convergence theorems, such as the Monotone Convergence Theorem or the Dominated Convergence Theorem?

Comment: @XanderHenderson I will check both theorems, thanks !